# What is the use of the gasmask?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I often find Gasmasks while playing (half or full).

Do they have any use; for survival in some regions for instance; or are they only cosmetic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All of the gas masks have no purpose in game currently.  They are purely cosmetic, like other items such as sunglasses.

Some sites saying they are cosmetic:

- [Game Wiki](https://pubg.gamepedia.com/Gas_Mask_(Full))
- [Indie Obscura](http://indieobscura.com/article/1043/gas-mask-purpose-in-playerunknowns-battlegrounds)

Comment: They are also purchasable on the market place, a game like PUBG doesn't seem to sell any items that can give players an advantage over others.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I think you can only buy clothing and items like this on the market for PUBG.  I left that out since the question was asking for in game uses.